# Return a a json object from an ajax call to a django view

Tags: ajax, django

Am trying to return a json object to render to a grid in my template.
This is how i do it.

```
views.py
def ajax_up(request):
    history_data=Upload_history.objects.all()
    history=serializers.serialize("json",history_data)
    return HttpResponse( history, mimetype='application/json' )
html
 $(".reply").click(function(){

      $.ajax({
    url: "/ajax_up/",
    type: 'GET', //this is the default though, you don't actually need to always mention it
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      alert("awasome"+ data)

    },
    failure: function(data) { 
        alert('Got an error');
    }

});
```

so i declare an object to hold the data as

```
var data = {{history|safe}};
```

where history is returned from the ajax call as in view above 
but when i do alert(data), i get [object object],[object object].....
can any one help please?

Comment: What's the reference to `{{history|safe}}` about? That's a django template tag, but there are not templated views here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's working, but `alert` just displays a string. Since your data is not a string, it'll show `[object Object`].

Either serialize the data with `JSON.stringify` or use `console.log` instead of `alert` to see the data in your browser javascript console.

Comment: it displays the same even in console!!

Comment: after i use json.stringfy, it displays the data correctly but the data is not parsed to {{history|safe}}

Comment: What do you mean "parsed to"? Where is "history|safe"? Note that you're using a django template tag - which only works in a django template rendered by django.